# PHP: How to loop through directories and exclude any that occur in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a code that lists all of the files and folders in a directory. What I can't figure out is how to exclude certain files based on a list of values in an array. For instance, I have an array like the one below. I want to reference this list and exclude any item that contains one of those substrings:

```
$hideDir = array('.php', '.html', '.css');
```

Here's my current loop. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($hideDir as $v) {
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { 
        if (strpos($entry, $v) > -1) {
            //do nothing
        }else{
            echo '<li>' . "$entry" . '</li>' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: you've got a lot going on there, other variables and functions that you're not showing here so it's hard to say.

Comment: `glob()` is a better starting point here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you should drop the whole foreach. Just check while reading the dir, whether the current entry's extension (that can be checked with [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)) is in the array, using [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array):

```
echo '<ul>';
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        // Get entry info
        $entryInfo = pathinfo(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry);

        // Is this a "hidden" extension?
        if (in_array($entryInfo['extension'], $hideDir)) {
            // Skip it!
            continue;
        }            

        // Otherwise, just list it
        echo '<li>' . "$entry" . '</li>' . "\n";
    }
}
closedir($handle);
echo '</ul>';
```

Notice that the extension does not contain the dot in front of it, so it should be:

```
$hideDir = array('php', 'html', 'css');
```

Comment: The only problem is that I'm looking to see if the array values occur as a sub-string of the directory, ie.: .php, .html, etc. Any ideas on how that can be achieved with the 'in_array' attribute?

Comment: @fireinspace Ah, like that. Updated the answer to reflect that situation.

Comment: @fireinspace Good to hear. I also noticed you tried to edit the answer and add an else clause. Note that this is not necessary, because the `continue` already stops the current iteration, so everything after that is never triggered.